# Record WebCam video using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying record video using user's webcam and save video. But when i click record button my javascript code gets following error:

```
script.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: webCamStream.record is not a function
    at startRecording (script.js:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (page1.html:10)
```

script.js:

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      webCamStream = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
}

function startRecording() {
    streamRecorder = webCamStream.record(); // gets error
    setTimeout(stopRecording, 10000);
}

function stopRecording() {
    streamRecorder.getRecordedData(postVideoToServer);
}

function postVideoToServer(videoblob) {

    var data = {};
    data.video = videoblob;
    data.metadata = 'test metadata';
    data.action = "upload_video";
    jQuery.post("upload.php", data, onUploadSuccess);
}
```

Comment: there's no record function on mediaStream -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `record` doesn't exist on a [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream),

you can create a `MediaRecorder` given a stream: [MDN MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)

example

```
const video = new MediaRecorder(webCamStream)
video.start()
```

docs example

```
startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
  }).then(stream => {
    preview.srcObject = stream;
    downloadButton.href = stream;
    preview.captureStream = preview.captureStream || preview.mozCaptureStream;
    return new Promise(resolve => preview.onplaying = resolve);
  }).then(() => startRecording(preview.captureStream(), recordingTimeMS))
  .then (recordedChunks => {
    let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/webm" });
    recording.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
    downloadButton.href = recording.src;
    downloadButton.download = "RecordedVideo.webm";

    log("Successfully recorded " + recordedBlob.size + " bytes of " +
        recordedBlob.type + " media.");
  })
  .catch(log);
}, false);
```

**Example from docs**

```js
let preview = document.getElementById("preview");
let recording = document.getElementById("recording");
let startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
let stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
let downloadButton = document.getElementById("downloadButton");
let logElement = document.getElementById("log");

let recordingTimeMS = 5000;
function log(msg) {
  logElement.innerHTML += msg + "\n";
}
function wait(delayInMS) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayInMS));
}
function startRecording(stream, lengthInMS) {
  let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  let data = [];
 
  recorder.ondataavailable = event => data.push(event.data);
  recorder.start();
  log(recorder.state + " for " + (lengthInMS/1000) + " seconds...");
 
  let stopped = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    recorder.onstop = resolve;
    recorder.onerror = event => reject(event.name);
  });

  let recorded = wait(lengthInMS).then(
    () => recorder.state == "recording" && recorder.stop()
  );
 
  return Promise.all([
    stopped,
    recorded
  ])
  .then(() => data);
}
function stop(stream) {
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
}
startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
  }).then(stream => {
    preview.srcObject = stream;
    downloadButton.href = stream;
    preview.captureStream = preview.captureStream || preview.mozCaptureStream;
    return new Promise(resolve => preview.onplaying = resolve);
  }).then(() => startRecording(preview.captureStream(), recordingTimeMS))
  .then (recordedChunks => {
    let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/webm" });
    recording.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
    downloadButton.href = recording.src;
    downloadButton.download = "RecordedVideo.webm";
    
    log("Successfully recorded " + recordedBlob.size + " bytes of " +
        recordedBlob.type + " media.");
  })
  .catch(log);
}, false);stopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  stop(preview.srcObject);
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px "Open Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

video {
  margin-top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.bottom {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Recording_a_media_element -->

<p>Click the "Start" button to begin video recording for a few seconds. You can stop
   the video by clicking the creatively-named "Stop" button. The "Download"
   button will download the received data (although it's in a raw, unwrapped form
   that isn't very useful).
</p>
<br>
<div class="left">
  <div id="startButton" class="button">
    Start
  </div>
  <h2>Preview</h2>
  <video id="preview" width="160" height="120" autoplay muted></video>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div id="stopButton" class="button">
    Stop
  </div>
  <h2>Recording</h2>
  <video id="recording" width="160" height="120" controls></video>
  <a id="downloadButton" class="button">
    Download
  </a>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <pre id="log"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: preview is a video element with id "preview"